# Running Echoip Docker Image

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker and having trouble running the docker image https://github.com/mpolden/echoip#docker-image. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$ docker run mpolden/echoip -a ./GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb -c ./GeoLite2-City.mmdb -f ./GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
echoip: open ./GeoLite2-Country.mmdb: no such file or directory
```

The files are in the same directory. To test on your end, download the files: GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb, GeoLite2-City.mmdb, GeoLite2-Country.mmdb: https://gofile.io/d/G4i6hb

Having a `docker-compose.yml` would make this much easier to run:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  echoip:
    image: mpolden/echoip
    command: "echoip -a ./GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb -c ./GeoLite2-City.mmdb -f ./GeoLite2-Country.mmdb"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The files are in the same directory

Docker containers cannot access the host filesystem unless it is mounted as a volume. For example, you could mount the current directory to `/data` in the container...

```sh
docker run --rm -v "${PWD}:/data" -p 8080:8080 mpolden/echoip \
  -a /data/GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb \
  -c /data/GeoLite2-City.mmdb \
  -f /data/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb \
  -l 0.0.0.0:8080
```

A Docker Compose config might look like this

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  echoip:
    image: mpolden/echoip
    command: >
      -l 0.0.0.0:8080
      -a /data/GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb 
      -c /data/GeoLite2-City.mmdb 
      -f /data/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "./:/data"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. That resolve the running but still doesn't run the service properly. `echoip: Listening on http://:8080` the url is not valid. Not sure if I'm using the right command: https://github.com/mpolden/echoip#docker-image

Comment: @Steve I missed the port forward for `docker run`. I've also added a global _listen address_

Comment: That works great! Thanks a ton! The volume and port totally make sense.